# Why does background image disappear, UNCHECKED - when the 3d view is closed, re-opened, or duplicated?

Tags: image

I open a blank project, add a background image, and an object.  Closed the 3d-view, opened it again and the background image was GONE.  I revert-to-saved, and image is restored.

This is NOT an ORTHO or PERSPECTIVE issue.  In my screen capture - you can CLEARLY see, on my the bottom window (which I thought was a copy of the same 3d view) - the toolbar, "BACKGROUND IMAGES" is UNCHECKED and the file does not exist.

Re-create problem:

1) open new project
2) Add background image
3) select "3d-view" from the bottom toolbar, where "timeline" defaults to.

[image: Screen-capture of issue]

Answer (score 1):

The background image settings are saved to the 3DView that the properties region is attached to. By changing another editor to a 3DView a new set of default values are used, they don't get copied from another 3DView.

If you setup the background images and then split the 3DView, then the background settings will get copied to the new editor.

Comment: I definately did not know this.  I tested this again, opened my map model - and created 2 3d views - and the map was on both views (after the file was saved, and saw "3" users tagged to the image.  I think after SAVING the file it was stored.  The first two times this happened, I don't know what I hit, since I wasn't expecting the background images (and settings applied to the image) to just vanish from the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Background images should be uniquely applied to each 3D-view that you want them to appear on, so for example changing your default timeline view into a new 3D-view will not mean that background images are automatically applied to that window. They will however appear in the list of loaded images if you activate the background image and click "Add Image".

On the other hand, if you switch the view mode for one of your 3D-views where you have a background image applied, the background image will stay in place for when you return to the 3D-view in that same window.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  I had been modeling a map for days, and lost my background images (with all the location, zoom, rotation settings for all the images).  Couldn't figure out what was wrong, had to revert to a saved file and lose last few hours of work.